# C++ overloaded operator inside template (metaprogramming)

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-meta-programming

I have the following simple program and I am trying to access values from the data array of class NVector from the sum template. How can I do that? Currently, I get the error below...

```
template<class T, int N> class NVector {
    public: T operator [] (int i) const {
        return data[i];
    }

    private: T data[N];
 };

template <class NVector> struct sum {
    enum {RET = NVector[0]};
};
```

error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in ACG_11_12 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
expected primary-expression before '[' token|
```

EDIT:

I want to eventually be able to do: `cout << sum<  NVector<int,2>  >::RET << endl;` and get the sum of the elements in data, but I will handle the summing part on my own. I want to figure out how to make `sum<  NVector<int,2>  >::RET` return an element from `data` for now...

Comment: what is `NVector[0]` supposed to be?

Comment: Please provide more context on how you want to use this. `NVector` in the second template has nothing to do with `NVector` declared in the first template. `NVector` in the second template is just the name you chose for the template parameter (it could have been anything else and using the same name only causes confusion). Also, `NVector` is a type, not an object, in the second template. You cannot index a type.

Comment: By definition you cannot access a data array in template meta programming. TMP allows access to types, enumerations and compile time constants.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Do you intend `data` to be a `static` member? Or what instance's `data` member do you intend to refer to with `sum<  NVector<int,2>  >::RET`? Also, if you want to use variables and functions at compile-time you need to (in most cases) declare them `constexpr`.

Comment: @walnut I don't want to change the `NVector` class, everything else will work fine for my use case

Comment: @Parankush ok, but then the question remains: What instance's `data` member do you intend to refer to?

Comment: @walnut I'm not sure I understand your question. I want to do something like `cout << sum<  NVector<int,2>  >::RET << endl;` in the end

Comment: Maybe you want something like: `template <auto> struct sum:
template <class T, std::size_t N, NVector<T, N> v> struct sum<v> {
    enum {RET = v[0]};
};`

Comment: @Parankush `NVector<int,2>` is a *class type*. It is not an *object*, i.e. an *instance* of the class. `data` is a *non-static member* and therefore each instance of the class has its own `data` subobject. `sum< NVector<int,2> >` is *also* a *class type* and `sum< NVector<int,2> >::RET` is a static member of that type, so to the `data` subobject of which instance of `NVector<int,2>` do you want the *static* `sum< NVector<int,2> >::RET` to refer to? You really need to provide a complete example program with expected output.